# Big O Time Complexity of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o

I am working with a piece of code and I was analyzing its time complexity. I think it is O(log(n)^2). Can anyone tell me if I am right and if not, please show me where I am wrong and what the actual complexity is. Thanks in advance!

```
for (k = 0, i = 1; i <= n - 1; i = i * 2) {
  k = k + 1
  for (j = 1; j < k; j = j * 2) {
    //some operations = constant time here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another great spot to apply the maxim

> When in doubt, work inside out!

That is, let's start by replacing the innermost loop with something that just says "do X amount of work," and keep repeating this until we're done.

Here, the innermost loop is this one:

```
for(j=1; j<k; j=j*2){
    //some operations = constant time here
}
```

The runtime of this loop is Θ(log k), which you seemed to hint at in your original question. In case it's unclear why that is, Θ(log k) counts the number of times you can double some quantity before overshooting k.

That leaves us with this code:

```
for (k=0, i=1; i<=n-1; i=i*2) {
    k = k+1;
    do Θ(log k) work;
}
```

Now, let's see how much work goes on here. We can see that the value of i will count out 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, ..., up until we exceed n. That means that the last loop iteration will be when i = 2<sup>lg n</sup>.

This means that, within the loop, we'll have k take on the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  ..., lg n. And since we do Θ(log k) work per loop iteration, the total work done here will be

> Θ(log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log (log n))

By properties of logarithms, notice that log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log m = log(1 · 2 · 3 · ... · m) = log (m!). Therefore, we have

> Θ(log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log (log n))
>
> = Θ(log ((log n)!)).

We can now use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which says that

> log (m!) = Θ(m log m)

to rewrite

> Θ(log ((log n)!)).
>
> = ***Θ(log n log log n)***,

which is the overall runtime.

Your original estimate of O(log<sup>2</sup> n) is a conservative bound on this quantity. It slightly overcounts because you're assuming each of the Θ(log n) iterations of the outer loop will do Θ(log n) total work, but since the earlier iterations do so little work compared with the later ones that turns out to not be the case.